# i am trying to get a method that estimates pi in java

Tags: java, methods, pi

Although the book that I am using to learn... says on the side note that it as a video note for this problem since I only have the  e-book I can access it to know what am I doing wrong....

If anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Note that I am using `m(i) = 4*(1 -1/3+1/5-1/7+....)` and so on

```
public class PiEstimationWithMethod{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
    public static double PiEstimation (double i){

        double Pi =4*(Math.pow(-1, i+1)/(2*i-1));

        Pi += (Pi);

        return Pi;
```

Comment: What is the problem? what result are you getting? and what are you expecting? Can you fix the code making it compilable?

Comment: where you are calling method!!

Comment: i  calling a method  afterwards for another class

Comment: public class TestPiEstimation {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 
for (double i=1 ; i<902;i = i+100){
 
 System.out.printf("%3.0f\t\t%5.4f\n",i,PiEstimationWithMethod.PiEstimation(i));
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly using of `java.lang.Math.PI` is not interesting! :-) I suppose you are going to calculate parted sum of series such [as](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%20), but forgot about cycle iteration.

```
int limit=100;
double v=0 
for(int i=0;i<limit;i++){
  v+=(1-2*i%2)/(2*i+1);
}
v*=4;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a loop in order to sum the terms that estimate pi. Consider doing something like this.

```
double sum = 0;
for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    sum = sum + Math.pow(-1, j+1)/(2*j-1);
}
//Note: the argument i in this function becomes the number of terms in the sum
sum = 4*sum;
Pi = sum;
```

Summations in math are often converted to loop structures.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oops. Starts at j = 1, not j = 0. Thanks!

Comment: Umm, I really don't think so. 

At j=1, first term is 1, at j=2, the second term is -1/3, at j=3, the third term is 1/5, etc. Add these i terms and multiply by 4 to get approximately pi.

Comment: Pay attention on (2*j-1) and series member in question.

Answer (score -4):

Use the `java.lang.Math.PI` directly.